# ASCII (from - to)

Tags: c++

I am working on exercises for school and I'm having a little problem: I don't know how to mark "from - to", like all uppercase letters in ASCII (65-90). I can't put in `-`, because it would mean minus. Here is my program so far:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    char letter;
    cout<<"Put in letter: ";
    cin>>letter;
    if (letter == 65)
        cout<<"Letter is uppercase";

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 90)

Comment: If that code compiles you probably need to upgrade your compiler, because `<iostream.h>` is not a standard header, and most compilers have stopped supporting it.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking as your code does not match your question.  What are to trying to achieve?

Comment: To check for uppercase with a single-byte encoding, you can use the C library's `isupper` function. You generally need to cast the argument to `unsigned char` to comply with the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works, im using different program, its SciTE with in build compiler + milions of different programing languages

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely use `isupper()` because

1. it respects the user's locale, and
2. there exist character encodings where the letters 'A' to 'Z' are on different positions and even with gaps between them, which means that the check `(letter >= 65 && letter <= 90)` will not work there.

This is, for example, the case of EBCDIC code pages used on z/OS mainframes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Compatibility_with_ASCII). `isupper()` handles those seamlessly.

(I was working on portable code supporting all those systems as well and you wouldn't believe, how many programmers and library writers make the assumption that the basic letters and numbers are always on the same position and in contiguous blocks.)

Answer (score 3):

c and c++ don't have a "from - to" statement or something like that. but you could easily write your own function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool between(char,char,char);

int main()
{
    char letter;
    cout<<"Put in letter: ";
    cin>>letter;
    if (between(letter, 'A', 'Z')) {
        cout<<"Letter is upercase";
    }
}

bool between(char n, char low, char high) {
    return n >= low && n <= high;
}
```

Comment: Prefer to use character literals instead of *magic* numbers.  Such as `between(letter, 'A', 'Z')`.

Comment: "Letter is upercase" should be "Letter is [basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) uppercase". A-Z are not the only uppercase letters in whatever character set/encoding that is likely to be used.

Answer (score 2):

`(letter >= 65 && letter <= 90)` means gerater or equal 65 and less or equal 90.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    cout<<"Put in letter: ";
    cin>>letter;
    if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
        cout<<"Letter is upercase";
}
```

Comment: A more readable solution is `if (letter >= 'A') && (letter <= 'Z'))`.